# Parsing json array to javascript array from file:

Tags: javascript, json, filereader

I am using html5 filereader api, this is my file:

```
{"menu_items":[' +
'{"name":"m_div_img1", "icon":"m_img1.jpg", "tip":"m_tip1.png"},' +
'],'+
'"desktop_items":[],'+
'"widget_items":[]}
```

This is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/radibg2/kemqpruu/2/
I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '
```

Comment: Does your JSON file actually look like that, with the plus signs and everything ?

Comment: Yes. It looks exactly like that.

Comment: That's not valid JSON, and it can't be parsed with `JSON.parse` because the plus signs and single quotes are unexpected tokens, they don't belong there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON you showed is not valid.

1. `"tip: m_tip1.png"` should be `"tip": "m_tip1.png"` (see the missing `"` symbols).
2. The `'+'` concatenation isn't valid, it is JS, not JSON.

This would be the corrected and a valid JSON based on your example:

```
{
    "menu_items": [
        {
            "name": "m_div_img1",
            "icon": "m_img1.jpg",
            "tip": "m_tip1.png"
        }
    ],
    "desktop_items": [],
    "widget_items": []
}
```

I recommend you to use a JSON validator in the future. They can be found online and offline (for more sensitive information). Like this one: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Please see the differences between the valid JSON I gave and the one you have. I think you can debug it further yourself!

Comment: I've tried with {"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]} from w3school example which works on their example, my code is the same and again the same error shows

Comment: The `'+'` concatenations are the things that break your JSON as well as the one mistake shown in the answer. Check your JSON carefully and use a JSON validator. You can do it!

Comment: Thanks i tried with the example from your answer and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**"tip:m_tip1.png"** needs to be **"tip": "m_tip1.png"**

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is saying that you need to remove the apostrophes from this file: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '`

If you need to have it all on one line, do so!

```
{"menu_items":[{"name":"m_div_img1", "icon":"m_img1.jpg", "tip":"m_tip1.png"}],"desktop_items":[],"widget_items":[]}
```

This will get you around the multiple-line restrictions, if that is what you're dealing with. Otherwise, what Sampsa wrote in his answer would be the cleanest option.

Answer (score 0):

What you posted looks like a piece of Javascript code that concatenates several string literals to build a string representing a valid JSON object.  But what you said implies that's a .json file, not a piece of Javascript code, in which case **you shouldn't have any of those ' + 's in there**.

Sampsa already posted a valid version of your JSON object. Just use that.